# Modificar placeholder al hacer focus en el input type text

Tags: css

Les explico. Lo que quiero lograr es que al hacer focus(selector:focus), el placeholder cambie alguna de sus propiedades, por ejemplo el background-color. Conozco la forma de cambiar el placeholder mediante el pseudoelemento selector::placeholder, sin embargo quiero que al hacer foco en el input, se cambie alguna propiedad del placeholder. Aquí dejo un ejemplo de mi progreso y el problema que tengo.

```css
input::placeholder{
  background-color:lightblue
}

input:focus{
  outline: 4px solid pink
}

/*¿Cómo hago para que el background-color del placeholder cambie al hacer foco?*/
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre"></input>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes lograrloespecificando el pseudo-selector `::placeholder` despues del `:hover`:

```css
input::placeholder{
  background-color:lightblue
}

input:focus{
  outline: 4px solid pink
}
/*especificamos que al hacer focus modifique el placeholder*/
input:focus::placeholder{
 color:blue
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre"></input>
```